# Universal construct for STDIN and Fileinput in Python Code

Tags: python, linux, unix

I want my code to be able to accept input from a file AND stdin.
What's the construct to do it?

I mean a unifying construct that implies

```
file1 = sys.stdin
```

and

```
file1 = fileinput.input(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unifying construct" sounds like you want to be able to access either a file provided as an argument or `sys.stdin` through one variable, so you can just tell functions to get a line from *that thing*. Luckily, `sys.stdin` is just another File object, so you have exactly the same functionality with both and it's as easy as a try/except block:

```
try:
  from sys import argv
  file1 = open(argv[1])
except:
  from sys import stdin
  file1 = stdin
```

You'll get `sys.stdin` if argv[1] is out of range (IndexError) or can't be opened (IOError).

If you just want to concatenate the two, use `file1 = sys.argv[1].open().read() + sys.stdin.read()`

Answer (score 6):

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    print line
```

Comment: `This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:], defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty. If a filename is '-', it is also replaced by sys.stdin.` -- http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html